# Add c++ function to existing python module with pybind11

Tags: python, setuptools, pybind11

How to create python submodules with pybind11?

I clone the python example (https://github.com/pybind/python_example) and modified it. Below is the directory tree.

```
*
|
+-- src
|   |
|   +-- example.cpp 
|
+-- setup.py
|
+-- python_example
     |
     +-- __init__.py
     |
     +-- cxx
         |
         +-- __init__.py
```

setup.py has the following lines:

```
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        'python_example.cxx',
        ['src/main.cpp'],
        include_dirs=[
            # Path to pybind11 headers
            get_pybind_include(),
            get_pybind_include(user=True),
            "include",  # the include folder
        ],
        language='c++'
    ),
]



setup(
    ...
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    ...
)
```

The following doesn't work because it cannot take names with dot.

```
PYBIND11_PLUGIN(python_example.cxx) {
    ...
}
```

The following also doesn't work.

```
PYBIND11_PLUGIN(python_example) {
    py::module m = py::module::import("python_example.cxx");

    m.def("add", &add, R"pbdoc(
        Add two numbers

        Some other explanation about the add function.
    )pbdoc");
}
```

This also does not work:

```
py::module m2 = (py::module) py::module::import("python_example").attr("cxx");

m2.def("add", &add, R"pbdoc(...
```

How to make this work?

Comment: Hope exists... This seems to be related: http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#partitioning-code-over-multiple-extension-modules

Comment: I think the solutions is different ;) Could you try to make the example more minimal (like use a module not a package) and more complete (specify what is the first module, what is the second; add example code preferably)?

Comment: i already found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cxx` is a sub-package and you try to build a binary module with the same name. Try to name your binary module differently to avoid name clash.

`setup.py`:

```
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        'python_example.cxx.cxx_module',
...
```

`main.cpp`:

```
PYBIND11_PLUGIN(cxx_module) {
    ...
}
```